# Get application.properties property at runtime?

Tags: grails

Is there any way I can get a property value in the application.properties value at runtime?
For example,  say I add a property named `application.type` into my properties file, I would like to pull this value out at runtime and display it in a webpage.  Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.5%20Versioning):

```
def appType = grailsApplication.metadata['application.type']
```